# Is it possible to change two states of different smart contract simultaneously in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

For example I have two contracts from two different car company.

The first contract World state looks like this.

```
Car_name: Volkswagen
Ownership: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And the second contract World state looks like this.

```
Car_name: Ferrari
Ownership: null
```

What I want to do is I want to change the first contact and second contract as below simultaneously.

First contract world state after changes:

```
Car_name: Volkswagen
Ownership: null
```

Second contract world state after changes:

```
Car_name: Ferrari
Ownership: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is it possible to do this and if it is can you tell me the name of this technique or some references that I can refer to in order to realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

Try to search keyword such as

「access data from another contract solidity」or 「update data from another contract solidity」,etc

Below Youtube Channel helps me greatly in understanding what I want to do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxU87o4U5iw

This website below also helps in my understanding.

https://www.zupzup.org/smart-contract-interaction/

Answer (score 0):

Perform the changes in the same transaction. All Ethereum transactions are atomic.

Any change to the outside world on the smart contract state is simultaneous.